# Regex to match spaces within quotes only

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I need to match any space within double quotes ONLY - not outside. I've tried a few things, but none of them work.

- `[^"]\s[^"]` - matches spaces outside of quotes
- `[^"] [^"]` - see above
- `\s+` - see above

For example I want to match "hello world" but not "helloworld" and not hello world (without quotes). I will specifically be using this regex inside of Visual Studio via the Find feature.

Comment: The problem is that the regex engine read your string from the left to the right and doesn't have any notion of what is inside or outside quotes (and doesn't have any memory too). Add a tag for the language or the tool you use.

Comment: `"(?=[^"]*\s[^"]*")` *could* work, but it depends on the possible input values. Can it have more than two quotation marks?

Comment: @FelixKling; no it's wrong too because you don't know if the quote at the start of your pattern is an opening or a closing quote.

Comment: @Casimir: Updated it and also clarified that it depends on range of possible input values.

Comment: @FelixKling That returns results in VS Find, but it also returns things that do not have any spaces in quotes, like `[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0")]`. Regex test here: https://regex101.com/r/40X0LG/1.

Comment: @Paul: That's why I said *could* and asked for clarification about possible inputs. This expression only works if there is at most on quoted character sequence in the string.

Comment: Gotcha. No problem. I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With .net and pcre regex engines, you can use the `\G` feature that matches the position after a successful match or the start of the string to build a pattern that returns contiguous occurrences from the start of the string:

```
((?:\G(?!\A)|\A[^"]*")[^\s"]*)\s([^\s"]*"[^"]*")?
```

example for a replacement with #: [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%28%3F%3A%5CG%28%3F!%5CA%29%7C%5CA%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%29%5B%5E%5Cs%22%5D*%29%5Cs%28%5B%5E%5Cs%22%5D*%22%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%29%3F&i=abc%20def%20%22ghi%20jkl%20mno%22%20pqr%20stu%20%22vwx%20yza%20bcd%22%20efg%20hij&r=%241%23%242)

pattern details:

```
( # capture group 1
    (?: # two possible beginning
        \G(?!\A) # contiguous to a previous match
      |          # OR
        \A[^"]*" # start of the string and reach the first quote
    )   # at this point you are sure to be inside quotes    
    [^\s"]* # all that isn't a white-space or a quote
)
\s # the white-space
([^\s"]*"[^"]*")? # optional capture group 2: useful for the last quoted white-space
                  # since it reaches an eventual next quoted part.
```

---

Notice: with the .net regex engine you can also use the lookbehind to test if the number of quotes before a space is even or odd, but this way isn't efficient. (same thing for a lookahead that checks remaining quotes until the end, but in addition this approach may be wrong if the quotes aren't balanced).

Comment: Does not return any results in the Find for the current file, and the current file does have quotes with spaces. Output: `Find all "((?:\G(?!\A)|\A[^"]*")[^\s"]*)\s([^\s"]*"[^"]*")?", Regular expressions, Find Results 1, Current Document
Matching lines: 0` It does work in a Regex tester though. I guess I blame VS...

Comment: @Paul: Unfortunately I can't test it on Visual Studio, but try to replace `\A` with `^`.

Comment: @Paul: you can also try this variant that ensures the contiguity but without the `\G` feature: `((?:(?!^)|^[^"]*")[^\s"]*)\s([^\s"]*"[^"]*(?:"|$))?`

Comment: I've decided to use the Regex in a C# method now. So your original Regex does match spaces, but it also matches the first word. For example "hello world". the regex matches hello AND the space after. I only want it to match spaces between words. Is it possible? https://regex101.com/r/rZZ3xt/1

Comment: @Paul: no it isn't, that's why I use capture groups to preserve all that isn't the target space, this way, when you perform a replacement you can put references to these capture groups contents in the replacement string like `$1#$2`

Comment: @Paul: see the demo link and click on the content tab.

Comment: I see. Thank you!